# List of correct urls not displayed in browser when in django debug mode

Tags: python, django, url, pycharm

Normally in debug modewith django, if you type a bad url the browser displays an error message with the list of available urls.
like it :

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blorp
Using the URLconf defined in bricole.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 
admin/
accounts/
[name='home']
accounts/
simple/
(etc...)
```

but in one of my projects, by typing a bad url I have the following result:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/phot" target="_blank">http://127.0.0.1:8000/phot</a>
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
“C:\Users\Lou\PycharmProjects\photoglide\phot” does not exist
```

and it does not display the list of available urls.

in debug the list of urls is not displayed in browser

I am with venv (django 3.1.2 and python 3.8 with pycharm)

I compared the .py settings with that of a project for which the list of available urls is correctly displayed in the event of a url error and the only difference seems to be:

the project where the url  debug works :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
 
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

... and where the list of urls is displayed (the project where the url  debug works fine):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

It seems that there is something with static. When it doesn't work it tells :
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

but even by replacing the static section of the project where it does not work by that of the project where it works it does not change anything.

Does anyone have a lead and the kindness to point it out to me?

Thank you and good evening.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was fixed in init.py by replacing this :

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

by that :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

and also by replacing this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))]
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

by that :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```